# this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#upload') return always null Polymer 2.x

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, dom-if

I'm having trouble accessing an element in the following `dom-if` template to add a custom event listener:

```
<template is="dom-if" if=[[!uploaded]]>
    <vaadin-upload id="upload" target="http://localhost:3000/uploadFile" form-data-name="doc" max-files="1">
        <iron-icon slot="drop-label-icon" icon="description"></iron-icon>
        <span slot="drop-label">....</span>
    </vaadin-upload>
</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="[[uploaded]]">
      <pdf-element src=[[....]]></pdf-element>
</template>
```

I tried to add event listeners for `upload-response` and `upload-success` in the `connectedCallback` this way:

```
connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#upload'))
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#uploadFile').addEventListener('upload-response', event=>this._uploadFile(event))
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#uploadFile').addEventListener('upload-success', event=>this._uploadFileSuccessful(event))
  }
```

The `uploaded` property is `false` by default. I searched in the [Polymer 2.0 docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/dom-template#node-finding), and didn't find a way to make it work. I always get `null`.

[image: console screenshot]

I have already used `this.shadowRoot.querySelector` in `dom-repeat` template without a problem. How do I make `querySelector` work with the `dom-if`?

Answer (score 2):

The `<dom-if>` contents aren't yet stamped in the `connectedCallback` even though the `if` condition is `true`, so you'd have to wait until the next render-frame with [`Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/namespaces/Polymer.RenderStatus):

```
Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, () => {
  const uploader = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#upload');
  uploader.addEventListener('upload-success', () => { /* ... */ });
});
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/aqENPm?editors=1011)

Comment: @syliaBARAKA No problem :)